# Hugo website is being successfully deployed to github pages but it is not being served

Tags: github, github-pages, hugo, toml, github-pages-deploy-action

I am trying to deploy static website to github pages - [aslon1213.github.io](https://aslon1213.github.io) - I am following the tutorial of hugo docs to deploy on github pages - created a static html and added github actions workflow from the given tutorial on hugo docs - [this link to docs](https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-github/) . When I push the code to github - The github actions is always triggered and shows successfully deployed but when I navigate to [aslon1213.github.io](https://aslon1213.github.io), it is not working.

Is there any steps I am missing ?
[IDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9OSd.png)
[repo_link](https://github.com/aslon1213/aslon1213.github.io)w

To make this work, what suggestions

Comment: Unrelated comment: you should bump your `actions/upload-artifact` to `@v4` instead of `@v3` to use the currently supported version of node, i.e., 20.

Comment: But it looks to me like it's working, you have a page visible at https://aslon1213.github.io/ at the moment. Did you fix this since you posted the question?

Comment: I was going to make a comment about missing permissions, but it looks like you fixed that in your latest commit. Anyway, I don't see an actual problem with your current deployment, so please clarify the question as to what is actually still broken, and why you think that's the case.

Comment: It looks like you solve the issue. Your site works for me.